# Copy button that fills the form with the data from the last entry

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I use VS 2012, c# and WPF.

So my user has a problem. She has a number of items to insert into the database using my program that are identical in everything other than the ID. So theres 200 shirts, that are all the same price and are gotten from the same retailer and all are in the same location.

This is what ive got, a method that is hit by a button on the form

```
 public void Kopiraj()
    {

        Adress oprema = _applicationPresenter.UbrzajAdress.First();

        oprema.IsNew = true;
        oprema.IsReadOnly = false;

        var obj = (from a in CurrentObjekti
                   where a.ObjekatId == oprema.SifraObjekta
                   select a).First();

        var pro = (from pr in _applicationPresenter.CurrentProstor
                   where pr.Sifra_Prostor == oprema.SifraProstora
                   select pr.Naziv).First();

       // this.View.naziv.DataContext = oprema.Naziv;
        this.View.naziv.Text = oprema.Naziv;

       // this.View.DataContext = _applicationPresenter.ListAdress;
        this.View.brojNaloga.Text = oprema.BrojNaloga;

        this.View.datumIsknjizenja.Text = oprema.DatumIsknjizenja.ToString();
        this.View.datumNabavke.Text = oprema.DatumNabavke.ToString();
        this.View.datumZaduzenja.Text = oprema.DatumZaduzenja.ToString();
        this.View.dobavljac.Text = oprema.Dobavljac.ToString();
        this.View.inventurniBroj.Text = oprema.InventurniBroj.ToString();
        this.View.jedCijena.Text = oprema.JedCijena.ToString("F");
        this.View.kolicinaNabavna.Text = oprema.KolicinaNabavna.ToString();
        this.View.kolicinaOtpisana.Text = oprema.KolicinaOtpisana.ToString();
        this.View.kolicinaTrenutna.Text = oprema.KolicinaTrenutna.ToString();
        this.View.konto.Text = oprema.Konto.ToString();
        this.View.kontoIsp.Text = oprema.KontoIsp.ToString();
        this.View.mjera.Text = oprema.JedinicaMjere.ToString();

        _applicationPresenter.LoadObjekti();


        this.View.objekti.SelectedValue = oprema.SifraObjekta;
        this.View.objekti.ItemsSource = _applicationPresenter.CurrentObjekti;
        this.View.objekti.SelectedValuePath = obj.ObjekatId.ToString();
        this.View.objekti.DisplayMemberPath = obj.LookupObjekat;
        //this.View.objekti.SelectedItem = oprema.NazivObjekta;          
        this.View.objekti.Text = obj.LookupObjekat;
        this.View.prostor.Text = pro.ToString();
        this.View.status.Text = oprema.Status;
        this.View.vrijednost.Text = oprema.Vrijednost.ToString("F");
        this.View.zaduzio.Text = oprema.Zaduzio.ToString();




    }
```

Thing is while it copies the data to the form its like theres nothing there, when i Click save the object is all nulls, like it didn't assign any values to it even though the textboxes are filled. If I enter a box with my mouse it seems to recognize the value and assign it but if I just click copy and then save (instead of tabbing through all the boxes like a crazy person) I get nada. I am especially struggling with the combo boxes because while it fills with the required text the rest of the box is empty, its not populated with anything but blanks.

If there is a better way to do this I'm up for starting from scratch, this was just my idea on how to do it. Also if there are any links or tutorials for this type of functionality, I searched google but came up with nothing that addresses my specific need.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When you hit `Copy`, does a *Text Changed Event* trigger? If you don't have one assigned, assign one and see if it gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by simply creating an object to hold the form values. This can be achieved either by data binding the properties of this object directly with the form fields, or even by manually filling it when the save button is pressed. When the form values are saved, simply re-populate the various form fields again from your object.

Comment: I have this copy object that is exactly the same as the one I have and I use it for refreshing and editing. Maybe I can use it for that too but I can't seem to repopulate the values. How would I do that? User opens up the regular new thing form, presses the button ok now in the method as u can see I assign all the forms to the values of an object (in my case not the copy but the actual object as i figure what does it matter, she is gonna insert a new object anyway, it just has all the same data, apart from ID) but getting wpf to play with my ideas isn't going as well

Comment: If you're going to write WPF, then you need to learn how to use it properly. We don't programmatically manipulate data objects like you are in your example. Instead, we use data binding... see the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with that.

Comment: I was being an idiot the problem I was having with data binding which I do use is that the property which was being bound was also kept read only and lead down a whole other path. What I did was on the hit of a button just change the IsNew property of the object to true which lead to other stuff and now it works. Thing is I am now trying to do a sort of batch insert, so user inserts max and min values and for each I add+1 to ID and insert... But not sure if thats a good solution? The way it is now the user has to manually change the ID, click save, change, save etc...

Answer (score 0):

As to the question part of "If there is a better way to do this", we solved this using a Save/Save and New/Cancel button option for our add UIs.

When "Save and New" is selected, the values are saved to the DB, but are not cleared from the UI. The user can then change the items they want, such as the incremental number, and save again.

Our solution is in MVC, so most of our code won't work for your WPF app. However the concept and ideas may help you out.

Let me know if you need more information or an expanded workflow on how we did this, and I'll write up a more detailed answer that could work for WPF as well.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea Martin I like it and I have the time to experiment with it but I would first like to get the core functionality working